# In a hybrid MVC and Webform site - need to leave mVC to an ASPX web form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

In my MVC portionof the site i am trying to hit \about_01.aspx.. but the URL remains in my global .aspx i have :

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}")
    'routes.IgnoreRoute("about_01.aspx")


    routes.MapRoute( _
        "Default", _
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
        New With {.action = "about_01", .id = UrlParameter.Optional} _
    )
```

The ASPX pages work fine and the MVC pages work fine but I cant leave MVC to Webform
roster/roster/#/about_01.aspx

Comment: Link example?  I'm doing something similar now and I don't have to do the routes.ignoreroute at all...

Comment: I just looked at my own links and I'm providing an absolute link instead of a relative one... not sure what you are using.

Comment: <a href="@Url.Content("~/about_01.aspx")" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-right">

Comment: tried this with same results: <a href="~/about_01.aspx" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-right">
            Home</a>

Comment: I actually have a FULL path instead of relative to the root so... `href="http://example.com/about_01.aspx`